# How to edit the last item in a recursively generate list with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, tree

Trying to do exactly what my question says, but I am having serious troubles doing it. DOM manipulation with jQuery is still new to me.

Here's my code:

**HTML - partials/institution-selector-checkbox.html**

```
<div class="institution-select__wrap" ng-click="checkInstitution($event)">
  <div class="toggle">
    <span class="icon icon-chevron-right" ng-click="dropDown($event)" ng-mouseover="institutionHoverOn($event)" ng-mouseleave="institutionHoverOff($event)"></span>
 </div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{ childInstitution.id }}" />
  <label for="{{ childInstitution.id }}">
    <a ng-click="dropDown($event)" ng-mouseover="institutionHoverOn($event)" ng-mouseleave="institutionHoverOff($event)" class='institution-selector-dropdown'>
        {{ childInstitution.name }}
    </a>
    <a class="entireGroupLinks" ng-click="selectEntireGroup($event)">
       (entire group}
   </a>
  </label>
 </div>
<ul style="display:block" class="ng-hide institution-selector">
   <li ng-repeat="childInstitution in childInstitution.child" ng-include="'partials/institution-selector-checkbox.html'" ng-click="checkForChild(childInstitution, $index)"></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
  var isg = document.getElementsByClassName('institution-select__group');
  $timeout(function(){
    var list = $(isg).find('li');
      for (var item in list) {
        if(typeof list[item] === 'object' && list[item].className === 'ng-scope') {
          var ul = $(list[item]).find('ul');
          function removeLastChevron(o) {   
            if($(o).children.length > 0) {

            } else {
              angular.noop;
            }
          };
          removeLastChevron(ul);
        }
      }
  });
})
```

My problem is that I want to edit the CSS of the rows of the lowest level of a dropdown tree, for instance removing the chevron from these rows.

Comment: What is the specific problem you are facing?

Comment: What do you want to do with the last item? If it is something css based, you can target it with `:last-child`. If you need to do DOM manipulation, you won't be able to do this with jQuery if you are using AngularJS. If you post the specific thing you want to do, someone might be able to help you.

Comment: This approach of searching the dom is all wrong! The whole thing can be accomplished with a simple `ng-if` or `ng-class` in the view. Use `$last` property of child scope in `ng-repeat`

Comment: But, say we don't have any prior knowledge about what data will be at this lowest level of the tree. How would an `ng-if` conditional know what to check for? Furthormore, I don't think `$last` would work because I'm not checking for the last element in an `ng-repeat` array, but rather from the last template to be rendered.

Comment: Take jQuery.js completely out of your angular page

Comment: what does `removeLastChevron()` do?

Comment: @charlietfl , this function should check each row's subsequent `ul` and see if it's length is 0, i.e. has no children. If it does, then we can edit these rows, otherwise we call the function again with that subsequent `ul` as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates a child scope for every item in the repeater. This child scope includes properties like `$last` and `$first` as well as `$index` that you are already using.

You could use `ng-class` and a css rule to hide your chevron

```
<div ng-class="{'last-item': $last}">
```

Alternatively to check for child data can use something like:

```
<div ng-class="{'no-children': !childInstitution.child.length }">
```

Then in css use something like:

```
.last-item .chevron-class{ display:none}
```

If you need the element removed entirely can use `ng-if` or `ng-switch`

Comment: I'm not trying to locate the last element from an array of list items, but rather from an generation of templates. The templates are generated depending on whether a json object includes an array called `child`

Comment: I think this is probably the correct implementation, I just need to work through it a bit more.

Comment: need to think data model first , not dom. Angular will manage the dom and provides lots of built in directives to help you identify how it builds it

Answer (score 0):

Given your image, you can target this with pure CSS:

```
.institution-selector li { /*this is all list items */ }

    .institution-selector li li { /*this is all second or third level list items */ }

        .institution-selector li li li { /*this is all third level list items */ }

    .institution-selector li:last-child { /*this is the last item in a list of items */ }

    .institution-selector li ul { /*this is a list within a list item */ }
```

etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the last child element, you can use something like this:

```
var lastChild = $('ul li:last-child');
```

Here is an example some working code: https://jsfiddle.net/297zk3tc/

Comment: This probably won't work with Angular generating the list, because the binding will get lost everytime it updates, and may not exist in the first instance anyway because jQuery functions tend to fire before Angular has loaded the DOM.